# KOMA: Keep layout when removing BCOR

Tags: xetex, koma-script, layout

I have a printed document where I used the BCOR option to add some space on the left for binding. Now I got asked to provide the same document again in electronic form. For this using BCOR would look ugly. However, simply removing BCOR changes the printable area of the page, changing my layout. My document does not even have the same number of pages anymore.
How can I remove BCOR without changing my document's layout? Like splitting BCOR to both sides.

Here is a small example which illustrates the issue.

```
\documentclass[paper=A4,twoside=false,BCOR=15mm]{scrbook}  % 4 pages
%\documentclass[paper=A4,twoside=false]{scrbook}  % 3 pages
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-17]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not sure that you can, honestly. You are removing a centimeter and a half from the margin of your document, it is bound to change. Also, “ugly“ is highly subjective. My advice would be to leave the document as it is.

Comment: I was thinking of splitting the 15mm to 7.5mm left and 7.5mm right, but have no idea of how to do so.

Comment: For this level of margin control, you'd probably have to use something like `geometry`. But this would almost certainly create many more options for LaTeX to break lines or add interword spacing, etc. They only really feasible way I see would be to “fix it in post“, as it were: Open your document in a PDF editor (like Acrobat) and move the whole text block a bit to the right. This can probably be automated or scripted, but still sounds like a lot of work in my book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you inspect the log file (with BCOR = 15mm), you will find:

```
(typearea)             DIV  = 10
(typearea)             BCOR = 42.67912pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 388.38017pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = 0%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 53.63345pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = 53.63345pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 595.80026pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -25.16531pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 17.0pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 20.40001pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 11.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 47.6pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 13.6pt
```

You can set `BCOR=0mm` and keep the same text area using

```
\areaset[<BCOR>]{<text width>}{<text height>}
```

**BCOR = 15mm**

[image: c]

**BCOR = 0mm**

[image: d]

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[paper=A4,twoside=false]{scrbook}  % 4 pages

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{showframe} % ONLY to show margins

\areaset{388.38pt}{595.81pt} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-17]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, this works great and is so simple! :-)
It also works the other way round, i.e. looking up the text width and height in the document without BCOR (the one for screen reading) and providing the dimensions in the print version (which can even have two-sided layout), adding a BCOR via the optional parameter of `areaset`.

Comment: @astoeriko Thank you for your feedback!